# Exchange Transport Rule

Tags: exchange

I need to create a rule that stops certain groups from sending email to the entire corporate office distribution group. However I need to be able to let them send email to individual members of said distribution group.

Is there a way to do so without having to allow each individual mailbox in the rule? I realize that would work but it would take a long time, also I realize that I could make another distribution group but I need to complete this ASAP. So for now I am looking for a workaround.

Any suggestions???

Comment: What version of Exchange are you using?

Comment: Sorry should probably included that it is 2007. I think I have figured it out though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Exchange 2003 you can set message restrictions on the Distribution Group so that only specific users can send email to the DG, or you can set restrictions to deny specific users the right to send email to the DG.

Comment: The same thing work on Exchange 2007 as well.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, the only problem was I did not want them to see the bounce back message. I created a rule to silently drop the bounce back and all seems well. Thanks for everyone's help!